# dJango forms.DateField

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am new to dJango and i encountered a problem while using forms.DateField,for example i inputted "2011-01-01" and my input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d'] so it will obviously accept it but when i input a value of "2011-01-1" django still accepting that format because django will read that value as "2011-01-01" and i dont want that to happen,i want to make a validation where in when i input a value("2011-10-1") like that it will raise an error...

Please help....thank you....

ok,i'll explain it clearly...here's my code:
class Info(forms.Form):
    bday = forms.DateField(input_formats=['%Y%m%d'], label='bday', error_messages={'required': 'Please enter your birth date', 'invalid': 'Date entered is invalid and should be in YYYYMMDD format'})

```
#I want to put here a validation(any validation)
```

and here's a problem...
If i put '201122' which means 2011 February 2,django will accept it because django will automatically convert that '201122' to '20110202' and i dont want that to happen,what i want is to make a validation that if i input 6 digits only it will raise an error,how will i do that,i tried every possible situation but django still auto-convert it... or is it possible to make a regular expression for forms.DateField?help pleaseeeeeeeeeeeeeeee....

Answer (score 2):

May I ask why? The DateTime field normalizes to a python datetime object, which you can format however you like.

Anyhow, you can do this with a custom field.

```
import re

class PickyDateField(forms.DateField):
    def validate(self, value):
        if not re.match(r'[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}', value):
            raise forms.ValidationError('Wrong date format.')

# ...
class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    pickydate = PickyDateField()
```

Comment: This is right - you should let Django normalize this to a Python Datetime object and then format it the way you'd like when accessing it later.

Comment: ok,i'll explain it clearly...here's my code:
class Info(forms.Form):
    bday = forms.DateField(input_formats=['%Y%m%d'], label='bday', error_messages={'required': 'Please enter your birth date', 'invalid': 'Date entered is invalid and should be in YYYYMMDD format'})

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this without writing a custom form field. Instead you can add a validator to your field like this:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def my_super_validator(value):
    if something_is_wrong:
        raise ValidationError('Wrong date format')

class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    mydate = forms.DateField(validators=[my_super_validator])
```